# How can I see output from a command progressively?

Tags: command-line, pager, output

I have fired an `ls -1` command that runs and displays a long list of values. When the command ends I can not see the output which is outside the screen vertical length. How can I see those previous entries ?

Is there a way to see the output progressively like :

1. Display first 15 rows
2. User hits a keystroke.
3. Then display the next 15 records

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pipe the output of `ls` to `pipe` as follows

```
$ ls | less
```

Then you are able to use less to browse the output, for example with <kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Page Down</kbd>. You can exit less by pressing <kbd>q</kbd>.

Type `man less` to find out more ways to scroll the output.

Answer (score 1):

On older systems, or systems not having the very good `less` utility described by Stephane, you can use `more` which is part of the [standart utilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/more.html).

Hit <kbd>space</kbd> to go to next page, <kbd>enter</kbd> key to go to next line, <kbd>q</kbd> to quit. You cannot "go back" and navigate into the output easily with `more`. `less` can.